# Get elements from list in python

Tags: python

I am new to python and was thinking of adding two lists.I have two lists `list1` and `list2`.
To get the result into a new list say `list3` , I can simply do this-

```
list3=list1+list2
```

But I want to take first `10` elements from `list1` and first `20` elements from `list2` and get the result in `list3`
From my experience in other languages,one method is to run a `for` loop for `10` elements in list1, keep the result in `list3`.Then do the same for `20` elements of `list2`. I want to know if there is some other way in python to do this without using `loops`. So my question reduces to can I get first `n` elements from any list into other list without using loops .
I am using `python3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using loop .we could use [list slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation)

**Code:**

```
list3=list1[:10]+list2[:20]
```

Answer (score 2):

That's easy to do with slicing:

```
list3 = list1[:10] + list2[:20]
```